# removeAll() is not removing objects

Tags: java, android

I have two Array list of self created class's objects.After comparison I am removing common objects from both and have prepared method for getting common elements.After finding common elements I remove common elements by calling removeAll() method but it is not removing that elements.I have used this method before but never got htis type of error.Here is my code :

```
public void SynchphoneBookwithDB() {
    //phone contacts
    ArrayList < Contacts > phone_contacts = CommonUtility.getAllContacts(ctx);
    Log.e("SynchphoneBookwithDb", "phonebooksize" + phone_contacts.size());
    //get data base contacts 
    ArrayList < Contacts > db_contacts = UserService.getUserServiceInstance(ctx).getNameNumberIdIsmycontactIsBlockedFromContatcsTable();
    Log.e("SynchphoneBookwithDb", "DBSIZE" + db_contacts.size());
    //get common contacts
    ArrayList < Contacts > common_contacts = getCommonContacts(phone_contacts, db_contacts, false);
    Log.e("SynchphoneBookwithDb", "common_contacts" + common_contacts.size());
    //not operation on common numbers so remove them 
    phone_contacts.removeAll(common_contacts);
    db_contacts.removeAll(common_contacts);

    //remained in phone must be added to db 
    Log.e("SynchphoneBookwithDb", "afetr removing contacts phonebooksize" + phone_contacts.size());

    Log.e("SynchphoneBookwithDb", "after removing contacts DBSIZE" + db_contacts.size());

}
```

Here is my method for getting common elements:

```
public ArrayList < Contacts > getCommonContacts(ArrayList < Contacts > referenced, ArrayList < Contacts > other, Boolean insertInDb) {
    //       Log.d("Inside common contacts","start"); 
    ArrayList < Contacts > commonArrayList = new ArrayList < Contacts > ();
    int count_ref = referenced.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < count_ref; i++) {
        int count_other = other.size();
        for (int j = 0; j < count_other; j++) {
            if (referenced.get(i).getNumber().equals(other.get(j).getNumber())) {
                commonArrayList.add(other.get(j));
                if (insertInDb) { //insert from server as it is 
                    other.get(j).setIsmycontact(true);
                    long k = UserService.getUserServiceInstance(ctx).addInContatcs(other.get(j));
                }

            }
        }
    }

    return commonArrayList;
}
```

Comment: have you implemented equals and hashCode for Contacts class?

Comment: ...And if not, then override them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like your objects are not equal! just their number field.

Override the equals method of your contacts class und use it to compare them.

[ArrayList#removeAll(Collection)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) uses [List#remove(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) which uses equals

> More formally, removes the element with the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))) (if such an element exists).

Comment: that means after overriding equal method I can now remove method what I have made to get common elements ...??

Comment: that what equals is for, yes